# Calling a function that moves the parameter value in a function that copies it

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I passed by the following code:

```
void enqueue(T&& value)
{
    move_value_somewhere( T(std::move(value)));
}

void enqueue(const T& value)
{
    enqueue(T(value));
}
```

The second function that copies the input parameter, calls the first function that moves it. Assuming the code is correct, how is that `T(std::move(value))` doesn't move the value instead of copying it if it's called from the second function, it's probably from `T()` but I don't why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `void enqueue(const T& value)`, a temporary `T` is being copy-constructed from `value` as input.  That temporary is then passed to `void enqueue(T&& value)`.

In `void enqueue(T&& value)`, another temporary `T` is being move-constructed from `value` as input (assuming `T` has a move constructor, otherwise it will be copy-constructed instead).  That temporary is then passed to `move_value_somewhere()`.  That temporary `T` is actually unnecessary, since `value` is already an rvalue reference, so it could be moved to `move_value_somewhere()` directly, eg:

```
void enqueue(T&& value)
{
    move_value_somewhere(std::move(value));
}
```

---

> The move constructor is called inside the copy constructor

Actually, it is not, because the code shown is not for *constructors* at all, simply for normal *non-static class methods*.  There is a big difference there.  *Constructors* don't have return values, and can't call each other like this code is doing.  But they can *delegate* to each other, but only from the member initialization list.  See [Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

Comment: Sorry for misleading, yeah it's normal method not constructor.

Comment: Since the above code invokes copy constructor than moves the value, is it faster if that function copies the data directly? assuming that we have function like `copy_value_somewhere()`.

Comment: If you are going to accept both copied and moved input, it would generally be better to have only 1 version of `enqueue()` that takes a `T` *by value* and takes ownership of that data, eg: `void enqueue(T value) { move_value_somewhere(std::move(value)); }` This lets the *caller* decide whether to construct the `value` parameter using copy or move semantics as needed.

Answer (score 3):

In `enqueue(T(value));` you first create a temporary copy of the passed value (`T(value)`). That temporary copy is then moved by your move constructor `enqeue`. So that code is similar to

```
T copy(value);
enqueue(std::move(copy));
```

Answer (score 1):

`enqueue()` takes a `T&&`, which simply restricts it to that type, no constructor invocation occurs as a result of passing the argument because it is not a value-type.

When you call `enqueue()` however, you create a temporary `T` which will have its copy-constructor invoked from the `const T& value` that you pass into it.

Subsequently, the temporary becomes the parameter for `enqueue()` which in turn, then creates another prvalue `T`, this time initialised with your (now) lvalue parameter cast to `T&&` which, if `T` does has a move constructor, will invoke it.

Otherwise, if `T` does not have a move constructor (nor an explicitly deleted one), it will "fall-back" to invoking the copy-constructor instead, if present.

Since you are passing a temporary to `move_value_somewhere()` it would need to accept either `T&&`, `const T&` or `T` - under the provision that the type `T` has a viable constructor to make this all possible.